# Why arent my headers registered on a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http

I have the following code:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function (data){
    for (let header of data.requestHeaders) {
        if (header.name === "User-Agent") {
            chrome.storage.sync.get({pua: "Non-Set"}, function (result) {
                data.requestHeaders[data.requestHeaders.indexOf(header)].value = result.pua;
            })
            
        }
    }
    return {requestHeaders:data.requestHeaders}

    
    
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["requestHeaders", "blocking", "extraHeaders"])
```

It is supposed to get the option value the user sets, and return that as the user-agent header, but it does not work at all! I used netcat, and my user-agent is normal!

However, if I hardcode the header value, it works! I am getting really annoyed.

I tried using `new Promise`, and awaiting it but that still didn't work! How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `chrome.storage.sync.get()` is asynchronous, there is no way to assure the callback of `addEventListner` return after the callback of `chrome.storage.sync.get()` is executed.

The alternative is that the request is always cancelled by the callback of `addEventListner`, and send modified request in the callback of `chrome.storage.sync.get()`.

Comment: could you provide code? this sounds a bit complicated since I am a beginner

Comment: In my idea, the original request is canceled, so it is difficult to use the response from the request in the same way as the original code.  Do you need to use the response from the request?